# Как соединить два файла csv в один и добавить при дополнительный атрибут через bash

Tags: linux, bash, командная-строка

В [данном упражнении сборника](https://www3.tuhh.de/sts/hoou/data-quality-explored/1-4-1-practical-task.html) используется набор данных, который называется wine.csv. Как пишет автор, его сгруппировали из двух разделены между белым и красным вином наборов “Качество вина” и в получившийся файл добавили дополнительный тип атрибута, содержащий тип вина (красное или белое).

Я хочу сам создать такой же файл, при помощи командной строки linux, например в bash.

При помощи wget я скачал наборы данных по [красному](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv) и [белому](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-white.csv) винам.

Далее я хочу объединить файлы в один, при этом добавив столбец type, в котором будет указан вид вина - red/white (как в файле из задания), но не знаю при помощи каких команд это сделать.

После всех проделанных манипуляций, я хочу отфильтровать файл, оставив в нем только вина с качеством больше 6 и содержанием спирта выше среднего.

Подскажите, какую команду или скрипт я могу использовать для решения данной задачи? Благодарю за содействие и помощь в решении!

Answer (score 2):

> Подскажите, какую команду или скрипт я могу использовать для решения данной задачи?

`bash`, `cat`, `echo`, `for`, `while`, `read`, `head`, `tail`, `cut`, `bc`

### Или подробнее

Оторвем голову у одного из файлов и запишем в сводный добавив столбец:

```
echo $(cat winequality-*.csv | head -n1)';"sort"' > winequality.csv
```

Прочитаем имена файлов по одному:

```
for input in winequality-*.csv
do
```

И без головы отправляем:

```
  tail -n +2 "$input" | \
```

В цикл читать построчно

```
  while read -r line
  do
```

Из имени файла извлечем тип, прилепим к строке и дозапишем в сводный

```
    echo "${line};${input:12:-4}" >> winequality.csv
```

И тут концы циклов:

```
  done  
done
```

Чтоб отфильтровать выше 6 используй if и cut:

```
quality=$($line | cut -f 12 -d \;)

if test $quality -ge 6
then
...
fi
```

Со среднем тоже самое, только нужно добавить ещё один цикл чтоб его сосчитать:

```
SUM=0
COUNT=0

for ...
  while ...
    alcohol=$($line | cut -f 11 -d \;)
    SUM=$(echo $SUM+$alcohol | bc -l)
    (( COUNT++ ))
  done
done

AVG=$(echo $SUM/$COUNT | bc -l)
```

Понадобился калькулятор - `bc`, потому как баш не умеет работать с дробными числами.

*П.С. учебник то по питону - может не стоит напрягать баш такими задачами?*